# EntityFramework 5 CodeFirst Child Parent of the Same Type Not Updating/Saving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have a `class` called Section

```
public class Section
{
    public Section() { construct(0); }
    public Section(int order) { construct(order); }
    private void construct(int order) 
    {
        Children = new List<Section>();
        Fields = new List<XfaField>();
        Hint = new Hint();
        Order = order;
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int FormId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Parent")]
    public List<Section> Children { get; set; }

    public List<XfaField> Fields { get; set; }

    public Section Parent { get; set; }

    public Hint Hint { get; set; }

    public int Order { get; private set; }


    #region Methods
    public void AddNewChild()
    {
        AddChild(new Section
        {
            Name = "New Child Section",
            FormId = FormId,
        });
    }
    private void AddChild(Section child)
    {
        child.Parent = this;

        if (Children == null) Children = new List<Section>();

        int maxOrder = -1;
        if(Children.Count() > 0) maxOrder = Children.Max(x => x.Order);

        child.Order = ++maxOrder;

        Children.Add(child);

        FactoryTools.Factory.PdfSections.Add(child);
    }
    // Other methods here
    #endregion
}
```

I am trying to add a new child `Section` to an already existing parent like this:

```
    private void AddChildSection()
    {
        var parent = FactoryTools.Factory.PdfSections.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == ParentId);

        if (parent == null) throw new Exception("Unable to create child because parent with Id " + ParentId.ToString() + " doesn't exist.");

        parent.AddNewChild();

        FactoryTools.Factory.SaveChanges();
    }
```

When I look at the database, I see that a new row has been added, so for example:

```
Id  Name                Parent_Id   Hint_Id FormId  Order
19  New Child Section   1           27      1       0
```

However, when I load the parent `Section`, the `Children` property is always of `Count` 0, like this:

```
    public ActionResult EditSection(int formId, int sectionId)
    {
        var model = FactoryTools.Factory.PdfSections.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == sectionId);

        if (model == null || model.FormId != formId) model = new Section();

        //model.Children = FactoryTools.Factory.PdfSections.Where(x => x.Parent.Id == sectionId).ToList();

        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Of course, when I manually add the children, then they are there (in the above code, by uncommenting the `model.Children = ...` line)

I am used to the NHibernate way of doing things and am therefore quite frustrated that the above, seemingly simple, task is not working in EntityFramework, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework won't eagerly load related entities. Try forcing it to include the children:

```
var model = FactoryTools.Factory.PdfSections.Include("Children").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == sectionId);
```

There's also a strongly-typed overload to which you can pass a lambda:

```
var model = FactoryTools.Factory.PdfSections.Include(s => s.Children).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == sectionId);
```

Comment: What assembly gives me access to the strongly-typed version?

Comment: Nm, just found it `System.Data.Entity`